# File download does not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular 1.2.27, and I'm trying to download a file. It works perfect on chrome but on FF nothing happens, the request returns 200/ok and the success code runs, but that's it, no file is downloaded:

```
var fileLoaded = $q.defer();
                    $http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                        .success(function (data,status,hdr) {
                            var cd = hdr('Content-Disposition').split(';');
                            var fileName = '';
                            _.forEach(cd,function(d){
                                if(d.trim().indexOf('filename') >= 0){
                                    fileName = d.split('=')[1].replace(/[\"]/g,'');
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });

                            var file = new Blob([data]);
                            var wurl = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
                            var fileURL = wurl.createObjectURL(file);
                            console.log( 'fileURL:' , fileURL );
                            var a = document.createElement("a");
                            a.href = fileURL;
                            a.download = fileName;
                            a.target = "_self";

                            document.body.appendChild(a);
                            a.click();
                            document.body.removeChild(a);

                            wurl.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
                            fileLoaded.resolve(true);

                        }).error(function (data) {
//                            console.error(data);
                            fileLoaded.reject(data);
                        });

                    return fileLoaded.promise;
                }
```

The only difference i see is when i log the `fileURL`. on chrome it appears like this:

```
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A9000/e869aa88-8190-4d9d-a379-9ad977a09613
```

And on FF like this:

```
blob:http://localhost:9000/f36b7773-00bb-4ade-87be-8f197c41ccf8
```

But I assume this is just a console thing.

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @Satpal - Thanks, works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting an answer here for reference. Using [FileSaver](http://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) from @Satpal comment, i was able to solve it easily:

```
var fileLoaded = $q.defer();
                    $http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                        .success(function (data,status,hdr) {
                            var cd = hdr('Content-Disposition').split(';');
                            var fileName = '';
                            _.forEach(cd,function(d){
                                if(d.trim().indexOf('filename') >= 0){
                                    fileName = d.split('=')[1].replace(/[\"]/g,'');
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });

                            var file = new Blob([data]);
                            saveAs(file, fileName);
                            fileLoaded.resolve(true);

                        }).error(function (data) {
//                            console.error(data);
                            fileLoaded.reject(data);
                        });

                    return fileLoaded.promise;
                }
```